# How to get out of the while loop if I receives a specific string?

Tags: python, sockets

My query is all about that I have make a raspberry pi as a server and I need to control the gpio of pi through another device using sockets.My server code is about that when I send string 'on','off','blink',through the client, the led must on,off,blink. Although led on/off/blink are all successful but i'm facing issue during led blinking. If the client transmits a string on/off during the operation of led blinking, then the on/off operation of led is unsuccessful.So how can I do that?
Any help is appreciated.

```
# server code
import socket
import time
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(12,False)

ms=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ms.bind(('',1234))
ms.listen(1)
conn,addr=ms.accept()

print('Connection Established from ',addr)
while True:
    data=conn.recv(1000)
    print(addr,': ',data)
    if not data:
        break

    elif data==b'raspberry\n':
        print('Hello Pi')

    elif data==b'on\n':
        print('led is turned ON')
        GPIO.output(12,True)

    elif data==b'off\n':
        print('led is turned OFF')
        GPIO.output(12,False)

    elif data==b'blink\n':
        print('led blinking')

        while True:                       #.... Here Is my query....
            GPIO.output(12,True)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            GPIO.output(12,False)
            time.sleep(0.5)

            if conn.recv(1000)==b'on\n' or conn.recv(1000)==b'off\n':  
                break

    elif data==b'exit\n':
        print('Goodbye..')
        time.sleep(1.5)
        break

conn.close()
ms.close()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Your code is not properly indented - please fix it.

Comment: You need to debug you code.  If print is working, print the data and make if statements accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you consume the received data, but you do not store it in `data`.

You need to store the received data in `data`:

```
while True:
    GPIO.output(12,True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(12,False)
    time.sleep(0.5)

    data = conn.recv(1000)
    if data==b'on\n' or data==b'off\n':  
        break
```

But then, `data` will be overwritten at the next iteration, by `data = conn.recv(1000)`.
Therefore, you need to respond to the on/off instruction at this very point.

```
while True:
    GPIO.output(12,True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(12,False)
    time.sleep(0.5)

    data = conn.recv(1000)
    if data==b'on\n':
        #on
        break
    elif data==b'off\n':
        #off
        break
```

---

As you asked for it, here is a simple way to handle a network application.

First, have a thread that receives the messages.

```
import threading
import queue

class Receiver(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        super().__init__()
        self.connection = connection
        self.messages = queue.Queue()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            message = self.connection.recv(1000)
            self.queue.put(message)

    def get_message(self):
        if not self.queue.empty():
            return self.queue.get()
        else:
            return None
```

Then, in your main loop, instead of waiting for message from `conn`, consume the queue of a `Receiver` object.

```
receiver = Receiver(conn)    # conn is the connection object returned by ms.accept()
receiver.start()

while True:
    message = receiver.get_message()
    if message is not None:
        process_message(message)
```

Ok so there's a lot going on here, but it's really not that hard.
First, I define a `Receiver` class, that extends `threading.Thread`, and overwrites `__init__` and `run`.
The `__init__` method is used to set the attributes that will allow fetching the messages, and the `run` method describes what the thread will do.
This thread will run a perpetual `while` loop, in which it will receive messages from the network, and put them into a queue.

By the way, the `queue` module give synchronized queues, among which, `Queue`.
It's a good idea to use these instead of a list in a threaded context.
Besides, it's not so trivial to get the objects from a `Queue` object, so I define a `get_message` method in the `Receiver` class, that will get the job done for me.

Then I instantiate the `Receiver` class, by passing it the `conn` object received from `ms.accept`, and I start my thread.
Finally, I run my main `while` loop, in which I consume the messages from the receiver's queue.

So what does it change?

The receiving methods, here `conn.recv`, are blocking, which means they halt the execution flow of their thread.
By putting them in their own thread, the main thread will not be paused.
Through the `Queue` object, the main thread can fetch data from the receiving thread, but without getting blocked.
If there is data, then it takes it. If there is not, it just continues.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i have already tried that, the blinking of an led doesn't occurs due to   data=conn.recv(1000)   waits for the data to be received. So due to this looping doesn't occurs.

Comment: @Keshav Oh, I did not think about that. Anyway, here is the way it's supposed to be done: have a thread that receives the messages, and another one that does everything else. As you understood, a network application has some blocking operations. As a consequence, if these operations share the same thread as the othe actions, the latter will be interrupted. Therefore, you need to separate them.